# ListBox GroupStyle HeaderTemplate with a color

Tags: wpf, silverlight, header, listbox, groupstyle

I would like to create a `HeaderTemplate` for `GroupStyle` (`ListBox`) which contains a rectangle with a color and the name of a color.

I have a list of employees. Each employee has a color. I used a ListBox and a `CollectionViewSource` with a specific converter to group employees by their own color. 
It works great! But at the time, I can only bind the property Name of each group in my `HeaderTemplate`.

Is there a way to perform this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Name` of the group will be the color, if you bind it to the `Color` property of a `SolidColorBrush` it should be converted automatically.

Comment: Thanks ! i used a specific converter.